# Displaying a one-time message to users after deployment (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I'd like to display a message to each user the first time they log in after a deployment, which describes the changes. I have some ideas about rolling my own. For example, I could maintain a table of messages and another which tracks which users have seen which. But it seems like a common-enough use case that I'm surprise I can't find a gem which does this.

Thanks!

Comment: Not to be nitpicky, but you didn't actually ask a question in your post. But anyway - this should be simple enough that you can develop it on your own if your search winds up fruitless. And then you can create a gem for it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a table of messages that have a `publish_date` column. If you maintain a `last_logged_in` column on a record for a user, you can get all the messages created since that person logged in last and display them.

Comment: Yeah I like this idea. Thanks!